# Android - XML layout vs programmatic

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to use relative layout with a custom class that extends view, and a couple of buttons. This is what I eventually want it to look like:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pe6Wn.jpg

(forgive me for posting a link rather than an image, apparently I'm not cool enough yet)

Currently this is hardcoded with heights in dp (see XML below), and there are two problems with this:

- It only looks acceptable on my Nexus 7 screen, and no other device
- Both custom views' onDraw method still provides a canvas with height and width that exactly match the resolution of the device

If I try to set layout_height to wrap_content, each custom view attempts to take up the whole screen, which seems consistent with bullet point 2, but clearly is not what I want.

What I want to achieve is a Relative Layout with two custom views, that looks exactly as shown in the picture, but will scale itself to the dimensions of the screen it's sitting on AND the custom views canvas actually knows how big a part of the screen it sits on. How do I do this?

Edit: the reason this is "vs programmatic" is that I think overriding on measure wouldn't be a bad shout, but I have no idea how that would interact with the XML. I'd rather have the layout definition in one place, too.

My XML is below:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".TrajectoryView" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.5" >

    <com.sportsim.virtualcricket.view.SideProfileView
        android:id="@+id/side_profile_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </com.sportsim.virtualcricket.view.SideProfileView>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.5" >

    <com.sportsim.virtualcricket.view.BirdsEyeView
        android:id="@+id/birds_eye_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.25"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:text="Button" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

This would be fairly easy using LinearLayout and weights. I've given an example below but I can't test it at the moment. It should provide some direction though.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".TrajectoryView" >

<com.sportsim.virtualcricket.view.SideProfileView
    android:id="@+id/side_profile_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"/>

<com.sportsim.virtualcricket.view.BirdsEyeView
    android:id="@+id/birds_eye_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.25" />

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.25"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:text="Button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a go when I get home. Will this preserve the state of the buttons (i.e. each take up half the width of the screen, and be next to each other?)

Not that it's a big deal as this is just a test activity, but I'd like to learn what I can from this

Comment: Ok, I'll modify it so the buttons are side-by-side. That should be ok now. Again, I haven't tested it and generally nested weights are bad for performance. You can replace the LinearLayout used to set the button positions with a RelativeLayout though.

Comment: Ah nice, yeah the RelativeLayout thing sounds pretty good - cheers man :D

Comment: Tested it. Should give you what you want. Good luck with your project!

Comment: I've tried some stuff out, but it's still not quite working as designed, I'll edit the question to display my new issues :P

Comment: You dont need all those child linear layouts.. there should only be the main LinearLayout and a child LinearLayout for the buttons.